# select COUNT query over two tables with group by and ORDER

Tags: sql

I have two tables. I need to query the top 4 most requested products of the last 7 days.
To do this, I connect the first table zstat_main with the second table products to see if the product still exists.
But I think I have to use two GROUP BY, one by product_id and one by ip_address.
Unfortunately I can't do it, not even with a sub_query. Can someone help, please?

Unfortunately, this query does not work properly:

```
SELECT COUNT(stats.id) as counter, aw.id, aw.product_title 
FROM 
    zstat_main stats, 
    products aw 
WHERE stats.product_id = aw.id 
AND stats.owner_id = aw.owner_id 
AND stats.site_name = 2423 
AND stats.owner_id = 1 
AND aw.product_id > 0 
AND stats.timestamp > 1652682254 
GROUP by stats.ip_address 
ORDER BY counter 
DESC LIMIT 4
```

Neither does this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(stats.id) as counter, aw.id, aw.product_title 
FROM 
    zstat_main stats, 
    products aw 
WHERE stats.product_id = aw.id 
AND stats.owner_id = aw.owner_id 
AND stats.site_name = 2423 
AND stats.owner_id = 1 
AND aw.product_id > 0 
AND stats.timestamp > 1652682254 
GROUP by stats.ip_address 
ORDER BY counter 
DESC LIMIT 4 ) t
```

```
zstat_main
________________________________________________________________________
id  | timestamp | ip_address        | site_name | owner_id  | product_id    

1   | 1652964701 | 13bd38b63ca0aaa  |   2423    |   1       | 12    
2   | 1653025537 | ad1cd81f27966da  |   2423    |   1       | 12    
3   | 1653143906 | 34a4030e9b10af6  |   2423    |   1       | 12    
4   | 1653163019 | 0c17da1841b6779  |   2423    |   1       | 8 
5   | 1653225325 | 0c9a1f0f3c7679a  |   2423    |   1       | 3 
6   | 1653225351 | 0c9a1f0f3c7679a  |   2423    |   1       | 1 
7   | 1653225355 | 0c9a1f0f3c7679a  |   2423    |   1       | 7 
8   | 1653225360 | 0c9a1f0f3c7679a  |   2423    |   1       | 2 
9   | 1653225386 | 400ad361c57b614  |   2423    |   1       | 3 
10  | 1653225393 | 25c2121e18911e7  |   2423    |   1       | 1 
11  | 1653241700 | 400ad361c57b614  |   2423    |   1       | 8 
12  | 1653242036 | d4d83f3a7b9c729  |   2423    |   1       | 12
13  | 1653242030 | d4d83f3a7b9c729  |   2423    |   1       | 7
```

```
products
________________________________________________________________________
id  |   product_title   |   is_active   | owner_id 
1   |   product_1       |       1       | 1     
2   |   product_2       |       1       | 1                     
3   |   product_3       |       1       | 1                     
5   |   product_5       |       1       | 1                     
8   |   product_8       |       1       | 1                     
12  |   product_12      |       1       | 1
```

Comment: I recommend you to use ISO sintax for your joins, avoiding mixing filters and join conditions in your query.

Comment: The `group by`, in most of the rdbms engines (you don't share yours), needs to include all the columns in `select` clause that are not using an aggregate function (in other words, in your case `aw.id, aw.product_title `), and you are grouping by other totally different (`stats.ip_address`)

Comment: Why `group by ip_address`? `group by product_id` to get counts. You don't use `is_active` in your query.

Comment: More than an answer, I think you need a tutorial about `group by`: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @ James, I am on the way to use tutorials, Sir. But at this point I need help, therefore my urgent question, sorry.

Comment: @ जलजनक, it may be possible that a user on one day is logged in with an IP and also is not logged in on that day, to mark this as one as one  i use group by ip_adress.

Comment: I've changed the query after researching articles about group by to: 
SELECT COUNT(stats.id) as counter, aw.id, aw.product_title 
FROM 
    zstat_main stats INNER JOIN products aw  
WHERE stats.product_id = aw.id 
AND stats.owner_id = aw.owner_id 
AND stats.site_name = 2423 
AND stats.owner_id = 1 
AND aw.product_id > 0 
AND stats.timestamp > 1652682254 
GROUP by stats.aw_id  
ORDER BY counter 
DESC LIMIT 4  

It works well. the only problem I have, an ip_address can be found multiple times. But I can't delete this with another group by?

Answer (score -1):

**After another researches I found the solution for both problems:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) as counter, aw.id, aw.product_title 
FROM 
    zstat_main stats INNER JOIN products aw  
WHERE stats.product_id = aw.id 
AND stats.owner_id = aw.owner_id 
AND stats.site_name = 2423 
AND stats.owner_id = 1 
AND aw.product_id > 0 
AND stats.timestamp > 1652682254 
GROUP by stats.aw_id  
ORDER BY counter 
DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).